# Play! and AWS - provider chain is not respected

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework

This likely going to be very simple.  I have a Play! app that needs to talk to AWS and i'm trying to get any secrets out of code, even in dev mode.

i have the following code in a function (minus the case class):

```
case class AwsCredentials(token: String, accessId: String, secretKey: String)
val client = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.defaultClient()
val token = client.getSessionToken
client.shutdown()
val cred = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
   .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).getCredentials.getCredentials
AwsCredentials(token.getCredentials.getSessionToken, 
               cred.getAWSAccessKeyId, 
               cred.getAWSSecretKey)
```

the `cred.getAwsAccessKeyId` and `cred.getAWSSecretKey` always fall down to the magic keys, not the ones either from the environment variables that can be set or the `user.dir/.aws/credentials` or from `/home/play/.aws/` directly as the service does run as play.

Locally with Play! running via sbt, this works just fine and uses my local keys, but as soon as I deploy it and start with an init.d script it no longer does.  I have confirmed its in the environment variables and we use other environment variables, that work just fine.

Ultimately this is a AWS issue, but since i can get it to work locally with ammonite with the play user, there must be something amiss in Play.

Thanks!

Comment: what are the variables that you use? If the instance is ec2, then you should be using IAM roles, instead of hardcoding the access and secret keys.

Comment: The issue with that is you need a security token when using IAM roles but only a user or company can use `getSessionToken`.  The ultimate goal is to use roles, so `AssumeRole` is next

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting anyones time that chose to read and ponder this issue, as the underlying issue, i'm nearly positive of is that, I need to provide the accessKey to `fineuploader`, so that is on the page and in role mode i need  a token which needs to be passed as a header as soon as i do this, i'm not signing the request with the `privateKey` that matches `fineuploader's accessKey`

If i figure out, or want to invest the time to modify the JS code, i'll post back.